How to set "not Starts with" in Odoo Mailing List filter?
I have a dynamic Mailing List in Odoo version 15.0+e
and I want to exclude all the contacts where Zip code starts with K.
Using debug mode, I set the code in Editor according to this as the following:
["&",["is_blacklisted","!=",True],["zip","not ilike","K%"]]

The Synchronization criteria then looks like

It says does not contain which looks strange to me. And it actually works as does not contain. But I need does not starts with, not does not contain. It excludes all the records where K is present in Zip code. But again, I need to exclude only the records where Zip code starts with K.
I experimented and found that in my case:
['zip', '=ilike', 'K%'] gives 256 Recipients where Zip starts with K and is shown as 
['zip', 'ilike', 'K%'] gives 697 Recipients where Zip contains K and is shown as Zip contains "K%": 
As we can see, = mark determines the difference between Starts with and Contains !
If I have to use =ilike for Starts with, I don't understand how I can connect not with =ilike to get Not Starts with:
not =ilike doesn't work, and =not ilike, and = not ilike don't work.

How can I implement Not Starts with logic in Odoo Mailing List filter?

You already found out a lot. You just need to logically invert your domain part with the NOT-operator "!":
["&", ["is_blacklisted", "!=", True], "!", ["zip", "=ilike", "K%"]]
The domain widget has no functionality to show this domain as correct text output, atleast not in Odoo 15.

do you know since what version of odoo the "!" is supported? I rarely see the implementation of this notation.

IIRC very very long. This operator has been around since I started working with Odoo 7. It is only used very rarely because the inversion of something can usually be solved using other operators.
